# java Array.newInstance throws ClassCastException, why?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, instance, new-operator

Very simple code:

```
    int[] a = new int[]{4,1,2,3};
    Array a3 = (Array) Array.newInstance(a.getClass(), a.length);
```

It throws an exception 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [[I cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.Array'

Where did I get wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new `int[]` array or a new `int[][]` array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.newInstance(a.getClass(), a.length)` creates a two dimensional int array (that's what happens when you create an array whose element type is an `int[]`), so it should be:

```
int[][] a3 = (int[][]) Array.newInstance(a.getClass(), a.length);
```

`Array` is a class used to create array instances with reflection, but array instances are not instances of that class.

BTW, if you intended to create a one dimensional `int` array (i.e. `int[]`), you should write:

```
int[] a3 = (int[]) Array.newInstance(int.class, a.length);
```